# Как правильно разложить if условия

Tags: javascript

Тут такой код, в котором несколько условий, они понятно накладываются.
Смотрел про несколько условий if, но в данном случае выходит не то.

```js
if (newsbchecker = true) {
        var newsbchecker = document.getElementById('NewsbChecker');
        newsbchecker.checked = true;
 } else { alert('Значение не задано!'); }

if (edocchecker = true) {
        var edocchecker = document.getElementById('EdocChecker');
        edocchecker.checked = true;
 } else { alert('Значение не задано!'); }

 if (gsmetchecker = true) {
       var gsmetchecker = document.getElementById('GsmetChecker');
        gsmetchecker.checked = true;
 } else { alert('Значение не задано!'); }

 if (ucntchecker = true) {
        var ucntchecker = document.getElementById('UcntChecker');        
        ucntchecker.checked = true;
 } else { alert('Значение не задано!'); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас  в условиях не проверка а присвоение `=` , можно просто написать:

```
if (mychecker.checked) {
 ...
 }
```

---

Вот то, что Вам надо, судя по комментариям:

```js
let url = '?email=name@site.ru&ItsChecker&ErpChecker&GsmetChecker';
let arr = url.split('&');
arr.shift(); 
arr.map(id => document.querySelector(`#${id}`).checked = true)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ItsChecker">ItsChecker<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Checker1">Checker1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="ErpChecker">ErpChecker<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Checker2">Checker2<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="GsmetChecker">GsmetChecker<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Checker3">Checker3<br>
```

Comment: В предыдущей своей теме я открывал вопрос получению данных с url, тогда Вы порекомендовали запросы, я все сделал, почитал, итого данные приходят с url в true, и выходит я дальше сделал условие .. если true то поставить чекбокс .... т.е. если NewsbChecker = true то поставить чекбокс, походу немного не так.

Comment: @Joseff не исключено что я по фрагменту кода не правильно понял что Вы делаете, Вы не показали как объявлены newsbchecker И так далее, но общий смысл не меняется, сложите их в массив и ...

Comment: var ucntchecker = document.getElementById('UcntChecker'); переменная. Не пойму, что в коде проверке указать, если все в массиве.

Comment: @Joseff опишите подробнее вашу задачу, вам нужно найти все неотмеченные ческбоксы и для них что-то вывести или как?

Comment: Мне нужно проставить чекбоксы на основании полученных значений, которые я получаю в url. вот пример, мой url ?email=name@site.ru&ItsChecker&ErpChecker&GsmetChecker, я получаю ItsChecker, ErpChecker и GsmetChecker. Идентично им назначены id чекбоксов. Т.е. если в данной адресной строке есть такие значения ставятся галочки в идентичных чекбоксах, если нет, то пусто. Значения ItsChecker, ErpChecker и GsmetChecker у меня приходят в true.

Comment: @Joseff обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно, я только в url значение добавил window.location.search;

Comment: @Все верно, в сниппете это не имело бы смысла, а так все понятно